# Error in rendering data using ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, callable-statement

I'm having an error while rendering data using ResultSet. I'm having this error **java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.**
Here's my code snippet

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Session session = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
    try {
        // test
        BeanLocator beanLocator = PortletBeanLocatorUtil
                .getBeanLocator("Mrcos-services-portlet");
        BasicDataSource bds = (BasicDataSource) beanLocator
                .locate("mrcosDataSourceTarget");
        conn = bds.getConnection();
        String sp = "{call TINChkSP(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
        callableStatement =  conn.prepareCall(sp);
        callableStatement.setString(1, tin);
        callableStatement.setString(2, branchCode);
        callableStatement.setString(3, rdoCode);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(6, Types.VARCHAR);
        // all other callablestatement until all the 27 params are complete)
        callableStatement.executeQuery();

        ResultSet resultSet = callableStatement.executeQuery();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 27; i++) {
                arrayList.add(resultSet.getString(i));
            }
        }
```

The output of my ResultSet is null and gives me **java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.** error. Please help thanks.

**EDIT**
I checked the System.out of each parameters using 
`callableStatement.getString(4);`
 `callableStatement.getString(5);`
`callableStatement.getString(6);`

and the outputs are:
`42141` 
`000` 
`126`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of your OUT parameters, after your `callableExecution.executeQuery()` should be in the `callableStatement` variable.

To get them after the execution you must get by its type, like this:

```
String valueForOutput4 = callableStatement.getString(4);
String valueForOutput5 = callableStatement.getString(5); 
String valueForOutput6 = callableStatement.getString(6);
```

I assume that you want to have all the 27 fixed parameters passed to `TINChkSP` database function/procedure in your List.
I assume that they are all of type `String`.
I also assume that the first 3 parameters are not OUT parameters, but all of the others are OUT or IN/OUT.

Here's a possible solution.

```
callableStatement.executeQuery();

// The first 3 elements are not OUT parameters (I guess)
List<String> values = Arrays.asList(tin, branchCode, rdoCode);

for (int i = 4; i <= 27; i++) {
    values.add(callableStatement.getString(i));
}

System.out.println("The list: " + values.toString);
```

You can then remove the use of `ResultSet`, because it's gonna be useless.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I've tried this and it worked! But what I need is the list of them. How can I put them in array list? I can get the values 1 by 1 but is there any other way getting the list of values? I know resultSet as 1 way but it won't work for me because of java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data. error :(

Comment: The ResultSet has no data, because it's calling a function/procedure. Do you see your values, one by one, in your OUT parameters? How do they look? Maybe you could add that in the question, so I can check and try to help you. In short, I imagine you could split them and put them in a List.

Comment: Yes I can get the value of my out parameters. Hmm How could I split them and put them in a List?

Comment: Please, add in the end of your question the string you're getting from the OUT parameter you want to iterate. If it's separated by coma, you can do something like this: List<String> items = Arrays.asList(outputParameter4.split(","));

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope this is what you need.